# LibgdxAI / Java AI Movement slower than setted?

Tags: java, algorithm, libgdx, artificial-intelligence

So heres my problem :

My AI-Agent got 2 behaviors, arrive and wander. But suddenly i noticed that the wander behavior is like 10 times faster than the arrive one. So i searched and searched but didnt found any solution for this problem. Heres what i did :

Render method :

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {

    world.doStep(GdxAI.getTimepiece().getDeltaTime());      

    AI_enemy.update(delta);

}
```

Thats not all, heres my enemy.update method :

```
public void update(float delta){

    GdxAI.getTimepiece().update(GdxAI.getTimepiece().getDeltaTime());


    stateMachine.update();

    if(behavior != null){           

            // this method, gets all needfull variable from the @Override methods, and puts them into steeringOutput
            behavior.calculateSteering(steeringOutput);
            applySteering(delta);

            wrapAround(getPosition(), Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

    }

    distance = calculateDistance(gameScreen.mySelf.position);

    stateTime += delta;

    checkMovementDirections();

}
```

So, normally all should work fine, but for no reason Wander is still 10 times faster than Arrive Behavior... What did i missed ? Could someone explain that tome ? O.o I would be very happy about some help, there no tutorials or even explainations about it ...

Comment: Any ideas why it wont work?

Comment: Some help Would be really nice ^^

Comment: Come on guys .....